# Odoo16: Where is the docs variable used in the template defined?

Tags: python, templates, odoo, odoo-16

I have created 2 recrods, action report and template for pdf, but I have never defined the docs variable in the model, so how can Odoo understand it, or is it defined by default somewhere? So what if I want to define additional variables like "text1" : "hello" to use in the template? Thanks All

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `docs` variable is set while rendering the report,in [_get_rendering_context](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L913) function

**1/** You can pass them through `data` to `report_action`

***Example: (from [employees summary](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/hr_holidays/wizard/hr_holidays_summary_employees.py#L31) report)***

```
def print_report(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    [data] = self.read()
    data['emp'] = self.env.context.get('active_ids', [])
    employees = self.env['hr.employee'].browse(data['emp'])
    datas = {
        'ids': [],
        'model': 'hr.employee',
        'form': data
    }
    return self.env.ref('hr_holidays.action_report_holidayssummary').report_action(employees, data=datas)
```

**2/** You can also use a [custom report](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/backend/reports.html#custom-reports) and define additional variables in `_get_report_values`

***Example: (from [holidays summary](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/hr_holidays/report/holidays_summary_report.py#L108C1-L124C10) report)***

```
@api.model
def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    if not data.get('form'):
        raise UserError(_("Form content is missing, this report cannot be printed."))

    holidays_report = self.env['ir.actions.report']._get_report_from_name('hr_holidays.report_holidayssummary')
    holidays = self.env['hr.leave'].browse(self.ids)
    return {
        'doc_ids': self.ids,
        'doc_model': holidays_report.model,
        'docs': holidays,
        'get_header_info': self._get_header_info(data['form']['date_from'], data['form']['holiday_type']),
        'get_day': self._get_day(data['form']['date_from']),
        'get_months': self._get_months(data['form']['date_from']),
        'get_data_from_report': self._get_data_from_report(data['form']),
        'get_holidays_status': self._get_holidays_status(),
    }
```